# simple word problem - percentage of salary

Tags: percentages

"An employee receives a bonus at the end of each quarter based on her salary for the year. If she earns $1,800$ per month, and her bonus is $3.5$% of her yearly salary, her bonus for the previous quarter is...?"

Book says answer $756$. They get this by  $12 \times 1800 = 21600$. Then $21600 \times 0.035 = 756$.

I don't understand the answer. It's my understanding that since her bonus for the year is $756$ shouldn't you divide $756$ by $4$ since the question asks for the bonus amount for the quarter?

Comment: May be her bonus of 3.5% of her yearly salary is her quarterly bonus. If it said the her yearly bonus is 3.5% of her yearly salary, then what you say is right.  In this context it is a little bit ambiguous and I think you should believe that the 3.5% is her quarterly bonus.

Comment: "receives a bonus at the end of each quarter" (...) "her bonus is 3.5% of her yearly salary" - so what is meant is that she gets each *quarter* a bonus based on her *annual* salary. Could have been expressed clearer by whoever wrote this question.

Answer (score 1):

When the question refers to her bonus it means her quarterly bonus, so their reasoning is correct. Her yearly bonus would be 14% of her salary paid in four installments of 756.

Answer (score 1):

1800 per month means, 1800*12=21600 per year.

Now, 3.5% of 21600= 756.

If I try to align the answer that you have, I believe that the lady receives 756 towards bonus every quarter. Otherwise, the quarterly bonus will be 756/4=189. The question seems unclear and you need to cross check once again.

Comment: " I believe that the lady receives 756 towards bonus every quarter."   Well, there's your mistake.  You are assuming that the lady receives the same bonus every quarter.  The way I read the problem, her bonus is recalculated every quarter, based on her salary for that quarter.  It is **not** calculated for a year, then that annual bonus divided by 4 to get the quarterly bonus as you seem to believe.